# App is working fine before release but after release the data is not showing on Page

Tags: maui

"Prior to release, thorough development the data from the services correctly populated the ViewApplication page upon clicking the designated button. And page display the list of my data. However, post-release, the page displays as blank, devoid of any data.

I was using listview. I also changed it from a stacklayout and used labels that bind my data.

```
        <ContentView  x:Name="upcoming" IsVisible="true" Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
              HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <!--<StackLayout Margin="7" Grid.Row="0" >-->
                <!--<Label Margin="10,5,0,5">Please see below list of your applications</Label>-->
                <Border Margin="0" Stroke="Transparent" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                    <StackLayout 
                    x:Name="LeaseAccountList"
                    BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding ApplicationToAlterList}"
                    >
                        <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>

                                <!--<Border>-->
                                <Grid  x:DataType="local:ApplicationToAlter"
                                Margin="0,0,0,10" Padding="10"  ColumnDefinitions="0.80*,0.20*" BackgroundColor="White"
                                  RowDefinitions="Auto,Auto,Auto,Auto" 
                                  RowSpacing="2" 
                                  ColumnSpacing="5">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding PropertyAddress}" 
                                        Grid.Column="0"
                                       Grid.Row="0" 
                                       LineBreakMode="WordWrap"
                                       Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                                       FontFamily="Headline" 
                                       FontSize="5" >
                                    </Label>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding TenantReference}"
                                        FontSize="5" TextColor="{StaticResource Green}"
                                        FontAttributes="Bold" 
                                        Grid.Row="1" Padding="0,15,0,0"
                                        Grid.Column="0"/>

                                    <Label Text="{Binding statusName}" 
                                    Grid.Column="1" 
                                    Grid.RowSpan="4"
                                    Grid.Row="1" 
                                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" 
                                    VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontAttributes="Bold"
                                    FontSize="5" >
                                    </Label>

                                    <Label Text="{Binding CreatedDate, StringFormat='{0:dd/MM/yyyy}'}"
                                       Padding="0,2,0,0"
                                 
                                       Grid.Row="3"    
                                       Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                                       FontSize="5"/>
                                    <!--<Button Clicked="Button_Clicked">
                                    
                                </Button>-->
                                    <Button  Text="Application to Alter" 
                                        FontSize="5"
                                        Grid.Row="2"
                                        Grid.Column="1"
                                        HorizontalOptions="End"
                                        CornerRadius="0"
                                        VerticalOptions="End"
                                        Clicked="Button_Clicked" 
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding .}">

                                    </Button>

                                    <!--<Grid.GestureRecognizers>

                                    <TapGestureRecognizer x:DataType="viewmodel:MyApplicationViewModel" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" Tapped="Button_Clicked"></TapGestureRecognizer>

                                </Grid.GestureRecognizers>-->
                                </Grid>

                                <!--</Border>-->
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                        <BindableLayout.EmptyView>
                            <StackLayout 
                             Padding="15"
                             HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                             VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">

                                <Grid VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                                    <BoxView BackgroundColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="Center"  ></BoxView>

                              
                                </Grid>
                                <Label Text="You have no Applications to view." Margin="0,4,0,0"
                                   FontSize="Medium"
                                   FontAttributes="Bold"
                                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                                <Label Text="Please visit web portal to add new application."
                                   FontSize="Small"
                                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                                <StackLayout.IsVisible>
                                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource AllTrueConverter}">
                                        <Binding Path="IsRefreshing" Converter="{StaticResource InvertedBoolConverter}"/>
                                        <Binding Path="IsRunning" Converter="{StaticResource InvertedBoolConverter}"/>

                                    </MultiBinding>

                                </StackLayout.IsVisible>
                            </StackLayout>


                        </BindableLayout.EmptyView>
                    </StackLayout>
                </Border>
                <!--</StackLayout>-->
                <ActivityIndicator  IsRunning="{Binding IsRunning}" Grid.Row="0"   
                        VerticalOptions="Center"
                        >

                </ActivityIndicator>
            </Grid>
        </ContentView>



    </ScrollView>
```

Before release everything is the data showing on my page but after release page looks blank.

Comment: this is most likely a code problem, not a layout problem.  You need to add some logging to your code to show what it is doing (or not doing) while in release mode